# html5: передача объекта с помощью элемента <form>

Tags: html, html5, get

как передать объект в значении параметра при передаче GET-методом с помощью элемента `<form>`?

необходимо получить

```
https://example.com?token=123&obj={"name1":"value1"}&obj={"name2":"value2"}
```

следующий способ не подходит:

```
<form action="https://example.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="123">
    <input type="text" name="obj[name1]" value="value1"> 
    <input type="text" name="obj[name2]" value="value2">
</form>
```

результат

```
https://example.com/?token=123&obj[name1]=value1&obj[name2]=value2
```

Comment: А для каких целей такое-вот безобразие? Что вы сделать то хотите, зачем именно так передавать?

Comment: @EVG это имеет какое-то значение? платежный сервер принимает только такой формат данных

Comment: Что за платёжка ? Быть такого не может.)

Comment: @EVG сам в шоке =)

Answer (score 1):

На скорую руку, дальше думаю разберёшься что к чему. А что за платёжка - напиши всётаки, не дай бог на неё попасть.

```js
$('form').on('submit',(e) => {
e.preventDefault();
var info = $('form').serializeArray(); 
var edit_url = 'https://example.com?token='+$('input[name="token"]').val()+'&' ; // url for request;
var url;
for (var i = 1; i < info.length; i++){ 
 edit_url += 'obj='+'{"'+info[i].name.replace('obj[','').replace(']','')+'":"'+info[i].value+'"}'+'&'
}
url = edit_url.substr(0,edit_url.length-1);
console.log(url);
$.ajax({
 method: "GET",
 url: url
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://example.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="1asdsa123123123">
    <input type="text" name="obj[name1]" value="value1"> 
    <input type="text" name="obj[name2]" value="value2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: про js вопроса не было, но всё равно спасибо) ...cбepoвcкий шлюз извращается

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff не понял,в смысле про JS вопроса не было?

Comment: вопрос был про решение только средствами элемента <form>. видимо, это невозможно

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff нет таких атрибутов которые заставят форму такое выкручивать, да и в JS нет методов стандартных под такого вида "запросы". Да и собственно какая разница как запрос передавать-то. Вообщем если помог - принимайте вариант.